# How is the activity "adjustResize" attribute actually works

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

These days I was learning when the SoftKeyBoard pop came, out how is the activity layout changed. Then I wrote a sample, and I found something strange.

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.margi.inputbar.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="2" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="3" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="4" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="5" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="6" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="7" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="8" />



    </LinearLayout>


<include layout="@layout/layout_input" />
```

This is the manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And I use the Android Studio DDMS tool to check the layout state.

When I hide the SoftKeyboard the layout is:

[image]

And the XML layout is:

[image]

The linear layout has eight child TextViews.

And then the Softkeyboard pop out:

[image]

The xml layout is:

[image]

The LinearLayout only has 4 child TextViews

So, here are the two questions I want to find answers for:

(1) I want to know that what actually happened when the SoftKeyboard is shown, where is the disappeared TextView?

(2) Is there any document, file or blog to explain this? I had read the Google's document [Google training](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html), but I'm still not very clear about this.

Comment: Your "Activity" remains the same, but is likely that the inputmethodeditor (IME) has altered the currently shown view, to add a "ScrollView" like system, that allows partial rendering of the screen (since there is no value calculating a part of the screen that will be rewritten). This is an "operational system change", so you, as a developer, cannot alter this behavior on your app, but your app can be changed by the O.S. Each IME can behave differently, and at least one IME Service is always active. How it will behave, depends on it.

Comment: i guess that the activity which with the attribute "windowSoftInputMode" will do some tricks, but i can not find the relative code in the activity source code .  so , i want to know , am i guess is right ?  if it is right where is the relative code in the Activity ?  if not , how did system know which View in the Activity should adjust layout  when soft keyboard pop out, and what kind of the policy to adjust the layout when soft keyboard pop out .

Comment: You can find the source code at `package android.inputmethodservice;`... focus on the functions: `updateInputViewShown()`, `setInputView(View view)`, `onCreateInputView()` and `onCreateExtractTextView()`... those are perhaps the most commons ones, Basically, the `InputMethodService` MUST know how it will present itself, in some specific scenarios, and the OS will call those callbacks for the developer. Note that this usually means about 50% screen usage (and thus an ScrollView with the current view as data), or in some cases, an uniquely extracted view and pretty much everything else used.

Comment: thks very much , i will try to read the source code to find out the reason .